# Finding the limit of $a_n$ for $\tan{\frac{\pi z}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

i need to understand some issues with the prove of the following exercise:

Let $f$ be defined as: $$f(z) = \tan{\frac{\pi z}{2}}$$

Its not hard to show that its Taylor series around $z=0$ is from the type of:
    $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{2n+1} z^{2n+1}}$$

Prove that: $$lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } a_{2n+1} = \frac{4}{\pi}$$

The solution is to define $g$ as : $$g(z) = f(z) + \frac{2}{\pi(z+1)} + \frac{2}{\pi(z-1)} = f(z) - \frac{4z}{\pi(1-z^2)}$$

Notice that $f$ is Analytic at $|z| < 1$ , yet now $g$ is analytic at $|z| < 3$, but it is also analytic at $|z| < 1$, there we can use geometric progression sum to show that:
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(a_{2n+1} - \frac{4}{\pi})z^{2n+1}}$$

And from the identity of Taylor series it would also be true for $|z| < 3$, so if we use $z=1$ we would get that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(a_{2n+1} - \frac{4}{\pi})}$$ has an existing value and therefore $$lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } a_{2n+1} - \frac{4}{\pi} = 0$$

My questions are:

1. How can we prove that g(z) is analytic at $|z|<3$, meaning how can
   we find  $lim _{z\rightarrow 1 } g(z)$ ?
2. By investigating $f$, how
   could one know to define $g$ as it is (does is has something to do with the residue of $f$ at $z=1$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb C$, being the quotient of two entire functions (namely, $\sin(\pi z/2)$ and $\cos(\pi z/2)$). So the singularities of $f$ are no worse than poles. The poles of $f$ are simple poles at the odd integers, and the only odd integers satisfying $|z| < 3$ are $-1$ and $1$. So $g$, being obtained from $f$ by "removing the poles" of $f$ in $|z| < 3$ (note $\text{Res}_{z = 1} f(z) = \text{Res}_{z = 1} f(z) = -2/\pi$), is analytic in $|z| < 3$. Since $g$ is continuous at $z = 1$, $\lim_{z \to 1} g(z) = g(1)$, which is the sum of the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (a_{2n+1} - 4/\pi)$.

Comment: But both $f$ and $\frac{4z}{\pi(1 - z^2)}$ are not analytics at $z = 1,-1$ ...

Comment: Hi, i understood that, but how can we prove that $\lim_{z\to 1} g(z)$ exists ?

Comment: @MatanL $f$ has a pole at each odd integer. The only odd integers such that $|z| < 3$ are $-1$ and $1$. So $g$, being obtained from $f$ by removing the poles of $f$, becomes analytic inside $|z| < 3$. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I still cant understand why adding what we did, removed the poles at $z = 1,-1$

Comment: @MatanL could you please explain more where you're having trouble?

Comment: How can i prove, that by adding $\frac{2}{\pi(z+1)} + \frac{2}{\pi(z-1)}$ to $f$, we have created a function that has no poles at 1,-1?

Comment: @MatanL it's because $$\operatorname{Res}_{z = 1} g(z) = \operatorname{Res}_{z = 1} f(z) + \operatorname{Res}_{z = 1} \frac{2}{z + 1} + \operatorname{Res}_{z = 1} \frac{2}{\pi(z - 1)} = -\frac{2}{\pi} + 0 + \frac{2}{\pi} = 0$$ and similarly $\operatorname{Res}_{z = -1} g(z) = 0$.

Comment: But having residue 0 does not say that the function has no pole at that point, take a look at $f = \frac{1}{z^2}$ ... 0 is a pole the the residue is 0 ...

Comment: @MatanL the poles here are simple.

Comment: Ok now i have my peace with this :) thanks

Comment: @MatanL Yes! That's good to hear. :)